# Python "for loop and def" practice and got "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Tags: python, for-loop, object, typeerror, iterable

Here is my coding as follows.

```
import random

import math

def count_hit_in_cirle(iteration):

    randX=random.uniform(-1.0,1.0) # returns a X random float in INclusive [-1.0, 1.0]
    randY=random.uniform(-1.0,1.0) # returns a y random float in INclusive [-1.0, 1.0]
    one_if_in_circle=0
    for i in range(iteration):
         def one_if_in_circle(randX, randY):
             if math.sqrt(randX*randX+randY*randY) <= 1:
                 return 1
             else:
                 return 0
    return (sum(one_if_in_circle(randX, randY)))

count_hit_in_cirle(1000)
```

But I got error like this:

```
count_hit_in_cirle(1000)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-4dcc579bc645>", line 1, in <module>
    count_hit_in_cirle(1000)

  File "<ipython-input-3-4fbc77f1c9ec>", line 11, in count_hit_in_cirle
    return (sum(one_if_in_circle(randX, randY)))

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

And then I tried:

```
return (sum(one_if_in_circle(randX, randY)))
```

Still I got error:

> "TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable"

Is there anyone who can tell me how I could fix my coding? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to create a generator. You need to put the loop inside the function, not around it, and use `yield` instead of `return`.

```
def count_hit_in_cirle(iteration):

    randX=random.uniform(-1.0,1.0) # returns a X random float in INclusive [-1.0, 1.0]
    randY=random.uniform(-1.0,1.0) # returns a y random float in INclusive [-1.0, 1.0]
    one_if_in_circle=0
    def one_if_in_circle(randX, randY):
        for i in range(iteration):
            if math.sqrt(randX*randX+randY*randY) <= 1:
                yield 1
            else:
                yield 0
    return (sum(one_if_in_circle(randX, randY)))
```

Your function is just returning one integer, not a sequence that `sum()` can iterate over.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works, but the result is still not what I expect. I need edit all coding structure, but thank you for your clarifying the difference between yield and return.

Answer (score 0):

one_if_in_circle is defined as int type variable in `one_if_in_circle=0` and as function in `def one_if_in_circle(randX, randY)`. Change one of them.